# Are GCM messages sent as an ordered broadcast?

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have seen a few posts that mention that GCM messages are sent as ordered broadcasts, and that the "android:priority" attribute hence can be used to to control which (out of several) receiver(s) that should handle the broadcast first.

For example: [GCM BroadcastReceiver setResultCode use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594431/gcm-broadcastreceiver-setresultcode-use)

However, I can't find any doc from Google that confirms this. Regardless of which priority I set on my different GCM-receivers, the broadcast seem to be un-ordered.

Are GCM messages really sent as ordered broadcasts?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found out why I couldn't control my broadcasts (which led me to believe that GCM broadcasts aren't ordered): I forgot to call abortBroadcast() to prevent the second broadcast receiver from handling the broadcast message:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast() :

> Sets the flag indicating that this receiver should abort the current broadcast; only works with broadcasts sent through Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. This will prevent any other broadcast receivers from receiving the broadcast.

So when I call abortBroadcast() only the first receiver handles the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

From Google [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#payload)

> A "message with payload" is not simply a "ping" to the mobile application to contact the server to fetch data. In the aforementioned IM application, for example, you would want to deliver every message, because every message has different content. To specify a non-collapsible message, you simply omit the collapse_key parameter. Thus GCM will send each message individually. Note that the order of delivery is not guaranteed.